# Use of Boolean? in if expression

Tags: kotlin, null

If I have a nullable `Boolean b`, I can do the following comparison in Java:

```
Boolean b = ...;
if (b != null && b) {
   /* Do something */
} else {
   /* Do something else */
}
```

In Kotlin, I can achieve the same by using the `!!` operator:

```
val b: Boolean? = ...
if (b != null && b!!) {
   /* Do something */
} else {
   /* Do something else */
}
```

However, the use of `!!` feels a bit sketchy to me, circumventing the null safety system.

Is there a more elegant approach for this?

---

*Edit* It seems I oversimplicated a bit. For local variables, as [Banthar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32831059/675383) shows, it does work. However, my Boolean `b` is actually a "property with a backing field" (I'm not really up to speed yet what this imposes). This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Why you need `!!b` and not simply `b`? (I'm not that familiar with kotlin, just curios)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Since `b` may be `null` and one of Kotlin's features is [Null Safety](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator), which gives compilation errors when trying to evaluate nullable references. Thus, using plain `b` gives a compilation error :)

Comment: But won't `b != nil` catch that  before checking the right side?

Comment: You would say indeed, but my IDE says otherwise. I do remember that something like that should work, I'll see if I can find something.

Comment: I think `val r = b?doSomething() ?: doSomethingElse()` should work.

Comment: I would have hoped that as well indeed, since the docs provide `val l = s?.length() ?: -1`, where `s` is a `String`. However, the `Boolean` 'equivalent'(?) `val r = b? "Yes" ?: "No"` doesn't parse.

Comment: Now I've come to think of it.. It might actually be intentional, due to concurrency issues. The field may be updated between the left and right hand side of the &&.

Comment: Related post covering null operators including "Safe Casts" which are where you ran into trouble. The special cases sometimes defeat the safe cast.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o/34498563#34498563

Answer (score 264, accepted):

You can compare nullable boolean with `true`, `false` or `null` using equality operator:

```kotlin
var b: Boolean? = null
if (b == true) {
    // b is not null and equals true
} 
if (b == false) {
    // b is not null and equals false 
}
if (b != true) { 
    // b is null or equals false 
}
```

Comment: note: does not seem to work with the inverse operator `!`

Comment: @Richard it helps to think b as a having 3 possible values: `true`, `false` or `null`. Then when doing `if (b != true)` you only know that b is not true, but you know nothing about `false` or `null`

Comment: eg2.`if (b != true) // b is null or false`
eg3. `if (b == false) // b is false`

Comment: This is the correct answer and makes sense in Kotlin, but coming from a Java background it may feel strange to explicitly compare to true or false or null within an if-statement, which may explain why this is such a popular question and answer.

Comment: `if (b == false) {
   // b is false 
}`  what if `b` is null ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow see the updated answer, I hope it is now more clear.

Answer (score 55):

If you want to cleanly check whether a `Boolean?` is `true` or `false` you can do:

```
when(b) {
    true -> {}
    false -> {}
}
```

If you want to check if it's `null` you can add `null` (or `else`) as a value in the `when`:

```
when(b) {
    true -> {}
    false -> {}
    null -> {}
}

when(b) {
    true -> {}
    false -> {}
    else -> {}
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Kotlin will statically analyze your null checks. This is fine:

```
val b: Boolean? = null
if (b != null && b) {
    println(b)
}
```

Even though this fails with type error:

```
val b: Boolean? = null
if (b == null && b) {
    println(b)
}
```

For more see: http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

You can also use "null coalescing operator" (which will work for mutable variables):

```
val b: Boolean? = null
if (b ?: false) {
    println(b)
}
```

Comment: The analysis works only for immutable values. If you need to do this to a mutable field, store it to temporary local variable.

Comment: That makes sense, indeed. The null coalescing operator is probably what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Banthar that is not completely correct (your second example would be `var`?) ... if it is a local `var` then the compiler can still allow the safe cast.  For more special cases, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498562/in-kotlin-what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-deal-with-nullable-values-referencing-o/34498563#34498563

Comment: null coalescing elvis can be moved to assignment
`val booleanVal = nullableProducer?.produceVal() ?: false; if (booleanVal) {}`

Answer (score 8):

From what I've seen the Boolean? is a result of a method that returns Boolean on an object that is nullable

```
val person: Person? = null
....
if(person?.isHome()) { //This won't compile because the result is Boolean?
  //Do something
}
```

The solution I've been using is to use the `let` function to remove the possible returned null value like so

```
person?.let {
  if(it.isHome()) {
    //Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: The first one compiles if you replace `if` block by `person?.isHome() == true`.

Answer (score 4):

first, add the custom inline function below:

```
inline fun Boolean?.ifTrue(block: Boolean.() -> Unit): Boolean? {
    if (this == true) {
        block()
    }
    return this
}

inline fun Boolean?.ifFalse(block: Boolean?.() -> Unit): Boolean? {
    if (null == this || !this) {
        block()
    }

    return this
}
```

then you can write code like this:

```
val b: Boolean? = ...
b.ifTrue {
   /* Do something in true case */
}

//or

b.ifFalse {
   /* Do something else in false case */
}
```

Comment: Yes,  in the case: b.ifTrue{...} or b.ifFalse{...} it's may be useful

Comment: I'm surprised these convenience functions aren't part of the Kotlin stdlib yet.

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin, you can do like this:

```
val b: Boolean? = true
if (b == true) { // if b is null, this should be null == true
    /* Do something */
} else {
    /* Do something else */
}
```

Comment: `b != null && b == true` is the same as `b == true`.

Answer (score 3):

For Kotlin what i normally use is

```
if (object?.booleanProperty ==true)
   { 
     //do stuff 
   }
```

this would only work when the property is true and the object is not null. For the reverse:

```
if (!object?booleanProperty !=true)
   { 
     //do Stuff
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myBoolean?.let {
    if(it) -> doSomething()
}

myBoolean?.let {
    if(it) -> {
        doSomething()
    } else {
        doSomethingElse()
    }
}
```

You can also choose to do something in the event `myBoolean` is null like this:

```
myBoolean?.let {
    if(it) -> doSomething()
} ?: doSomethingInCaseOfNull()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use an **`if-else`** statement with an `Elvis Operator`:

```
val a: Boolean?
val b: Boolean?

a = true
b = null

if (a != null ?: b) { 
    println("One of them isn't nullable...")
} else {
    println("Both are nullables!")
}
```

> // Result: "One of them isn't nullable..."

```
a = null
b = null

if (a != null ?: b) { 
    println("One of them isn't nullable...")
} else {
    println("Both are nullables!")
}
```

> // Result: "Both are nullables!"

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to add an extension function if that helps you.

```
fun Boolean?.orDefault(default: Boolean = false): Boolean {
    if (this == null)
        return default
    return this
}

var x: Boolean? = null

if(x.orDefault()) {
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In case if you want to perform operations alike `contain` on a
>   `String` you could use equality check like below -

```
if (url?.contains("xxx") == true){
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can cast `Boolean?` to `Boolean` by using operator `?:` and returning `false`. if `Boolean?` is `null` it will return `false` value instead `null`

```kotlin
val b: Boolean? = null

if(b ?: false == true ) {
  //some action
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do with safe Operator "let"

```
val b: Boolean? = null
b?.let { flag ->
    if(flag){
        // true Block
    } else {
        // false Block
    }
}
```

Comment: This is simply not true, and will return in an exception being thrown.

Comment: Edited my answer based on the previous comment