# How to simplify this kotlin code if it needs both boolean and nullable checking?

Tags: kotlin

A `dataConfig` object has a nullable Boolean field `urlIsabled`, and would like to return based on whether the `dataConfig.urlIsabled` == null or the negative of the the `dataConfig.urlIsabled`

```
val result = if (dataConfig.urlIsabled != null) (dataConfig.urlIsabled != true) else true)
```

could it be simplified?

Comment: See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32830904

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plot a simple truth table:

```
| dataConfig.urlIsabled | result |
|-----------------------|--------|
|        null           |  true  |
|        true           |  false |
|        false          |  true  |
|-----------------------|--------|
```

So the result is `true` in all cases except when `urlIsabled` equals `true`. Thus it can be expressed as:

```
val result = dataConfig.urlIsabled != true
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to return `true` if `dataConfig.urlIsDisabled` is `null` or `false`.

Just invert the logic and return `false` if value is equal to `true`:

`val result = !(dataConfig.urlIsabled == true)`

Answer (score 0):

Can be simplified as:

```
val result = dataConfig.urlIsabled in listOf(false, null)
```