# Kotlin: Best way to express "`String?` contains `String`"

Tags: kotlin, readability

This *might* be simply a duplicate of [Use of Boolean? in if expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830904/use-of-boolean-in-if-expression), but I don't know enough Kotlin to know whether it is...

I want to test whether `body : String?` contains `expected : String` as a substring. (If `body` is `null`, then it doesn't contain the substring.)  I've figured out that I can write my condition like this:

```
    if (body?.contains(expected) == true) {
        succeed()
    }
```

or like this:

```
    if (body?.contains(expected) != true) {
        fail()
    }
```

(where `body?.contains(expected)` is an expression of type `Boolean?`), but is that really the *best* or *most idiomatic* way of writing such a condition? Are there any alternatives (possibly using other member functions of `String`) that are easier on the eyes?

Comment: I ask because there are little idioms like [`listOfNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of-not-null.html) that turned out to be big breakthroughs in readability, for me.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with both options but the first one looks a bit more readable if you are looking for the case when `body` does contain `expected`

Comment: I agree with @VitaliiIlchenko, I use and see the first one usually because it's more readable than the second.

Answer (score 5):

What you posted is what the default code inspector recommends you change it to if you type something like

```
if (body?.contains(expected) ?: false)
```

so your version can be considered idiomatic.

If it's known that `expected` will not be empty, you might consider it easier to read like this:

```
if (body.orEmpty().contains(expected))
```

or

```
if (expected in body.orEmpty())
```